# With x11 get window at coordinates

Tags: x11

I want to get the top most window that is at position x and y. In Winapi I do this with `WindowFromPoint` seen here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Is there any equivalent in x11? I have covered the entire screen with a window and i want to know all the windows that are at the point in z order.

Comment: use [XQueryTree](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html)

Comment: I think that's what Ill have to do, as XQueryPointer wont give me whats behind the current window. With XQueryTree I'll be able to detect which monitor its on too no? :) May you please move it to solution Ill accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XQueryTree](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html) gives list of window in the stacking order. You would need to query dimensions for every window in the list and stop when your point is within rectangle

Comment: Thank you so much!! Will I need to test if window is hidden or not?

Comment: yes, you call [GetGeometry](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#requests:GetGeometry) to get rectangle and [GetWindowAttributes](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#requests:GetWindowAttributes) to test for map-state

Comment: Thanks Andrey will test :)

Comment: Hey Andrey excuse my protege he asked some questions I already had answers too. He's an excited kid though :) I did your trick to test `GetWindowAttributes` and take only the `IsViewable` ones which is great it reduced from 300 windows to 50, however there are still many windows that are not visible it seems, is there anything else to test for visibility, this is my code: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/workers/MainWorker.js#L254-L260 we have windows that are like 1px x 1px and have title "nautilus" etc

Comment: , here is screenshot of these weird windows, we can see based on their size dimensions: ![](http://i.imgur.com/e3BtezO.png) any idea on how to exclude them? :) but more interestingly do you know what these windows are? it seems Firefox even gets one, its interesting.

Comment: looks like all of them out of the screen ( not sure why they are mapped ) - maybe used for some kind of properties / selections based mechanism